# How to play multi-channel audio from WAV file using Naudio?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm fairly new to NAudio and I'm trying to load audio channels from a WAV file into WaveStreams and display each of those channels in its own WaveViewer.

How can I go about this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found here:

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.no/2012/01/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.